# Run MultiSelect on load not on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the following code to run on page load and not when a hyperlink is clicked as it does currently. I am using a jQuery plugin called [MultiSelect](https://springstubbe.us/projects/jquery-multiselect/).

I would like to know which parts of the jQuery script I need to remove and what I need to replace them with.

I am hoping to populate the jQuery values with PHP variables so that I can pull the results from a MySQL database so they can be updated.

```
<li class="clear">
        <h4>Dynamically Populate List</h4>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle Plugin</a>
        <div class="render">
            <select name="" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
            <a href="#" class="loadoptions">Populate List</a><br/>
            <a href="#" class="dpopgetvalues">Get Selected Values</a>
        </div>
        <div class="code">
            <script>
$('select[multiple]').multiselect({
    columns  : 3,
    search   : true,
    selectAll: true
});

$('select[multiple]').siblings('a.loadoptions')
    .click(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();

        var options = [{
            name   : 'Option 1',
            value  : 1,
            checked: false
        },{
            name   : 'Option 2',
            value  : 2,
            checked: true
        },{
            name   : 'Option 3',
            value  : 3,
            checked: false
        },{
            name   : 'Option 4',
            value  : 4,
            checked: true
        },{
            name   : 'Option 5',
            value  : 5,
            checked: false
        }];

        $(this).siblings('select[multiple]')
            .multiselect('loadOptions', options );
    });

$('select[multiple]').siblings('a.dpopgetvalues')
    .click(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();

        alert(
            'Selected Values: '
           + $(this).siblings('select[multiple]').val()
        );
    });</script>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Thanks for any help on this.

John

Comment: Is your JS logic actually in `<code>` tags, or have you just done that as part of the formatting of this question?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan They are actually <script> tags.

Comment: Can you share a working example? Your question is not complete. Because if you are going to populate the list from PHP why are you trying to do it again with JS. just populate the content and initialize the plugin in DOM ready.

Comment: @JeradRutnam At the moment I just want to be able to load the options on page load and not when a hyperlink is clicked. Just don't know what to replace the code above with.

Comment: There are few ways of doing it so. So im still not clear about your question. 1st you can just keep the options within the select tag in statically. 2nd you can populate them dynamically from a server side language like PHP. 3rd you can inject them by a client side scripting language like javascript. And you need to initialize the multi-select after everything is done. Till that you will just have a `<select>` tag with its content.

Answer (score 0):

Try activating by trigging a custom event event `}).trigger('set-config');` at the end of where it is.

NOTE:
 <s>it does not seem to have proper CSS in spite of me grabbing some from the site linked but that is not really the question here.  I also grabbed the .js for the plugin from a CDN so not an exact match perhaps.</s>

I removed my attempts to make a "working" version here due to issues/cdn etc.

```js
$(function() {
  $('select[multiple]').multiselect({
    columns: 3,
    search: true,
    selectAll: true
  });

  $('select[multiple]').on('set-config',
    function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // get this via ajax perhaps here?
      var options = [{
        name: 'Option 1',
        value: 1,
        checked: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 2',
        value: 2,
        checked: true
      }, {
        name: 'Option 3',
        value: 3,
        checked: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 4',
        value: 4,
        checked: true
      }, {
        name: 'Option 5',
        value: 5,
        checked: false
      }];

      $(this).multiselect('loadOptions', options);
    }).trigger('set-config');

  $('select[multiple]').siblings('a.dpopgetvalues')
    .click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      alert(
        'Selected Values: ' +
        $(this).siblings('select[multiple]').val()
      );
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide feedback on if this did or did not work and if it did and no other answers provide an appropriate solution consider accepting this one as the answer or if not, please elaborate why so it can possibly be enhanced.